# Symfony @Assert\Regex preg_ereg

Tags: regex, symfony, assert

I'm trying to validate this:

```
(000 - 001 - 002 ..... 099 ... 100)
```

Use in symfony entity:

```
@Assert\Regex("/^(0[1-9][0-9]|100)$/")
```

This pattern in pcre/php is ok but in the symfony validator it does not work.

I've tried to put 007 and form return (invalid input).

Comment: Could you add form code ?

Comment: Form code is auto generate from symfony.   symfony try to validate input end result not valid but regex is ok ( i thinks is wrong format for assert synfony)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong regexp. It will not work for `007`.

The right one will be:

```
"/^(0[0-9][0-9]|100)$/"
```

Comment: Thanks Michael . Big mistake from copy and paste in my code. Close topic problem solved!

Comment: You should close it yourself. Or check my answer as right. But I recommend you to delete your question.

Comment: Hi, cant delete with reply. how do close?